# Final-Mile Shipping Company Wants Customer Email Address - PCI Compliance Issue? (United States)

Tags: pci-dss, e-commerce

My company ships very large, very heavy products to the homes of everyday consumers (think big home renovation materials). Currently, we provide the customer's name, shipping address, and phone number to the factory. The factory then provides that information to a freight company who will then provides it to a final-mile delivery company.

The final-mile delivery company wants us to provide the customer's email address so they can improve the delivery time frame. Customers are significantly more likely to respond to an email than they are to a phone call. Text messaging isn't, apparently, effective enough either, because there are still land lines in play.

We ship only to the continental United States, so we don't fall immediately under the GDPR umbrella, but my concern is that providing this email address to other businesses in our manufacturing and delivery pipeline will have PCI compliance consequences.

It would be simple if I could just add a disclaimer into our Terms and Conditions that explains that we will give the customer's email address to other entities for the purposes of shipping and delivery, but that information won't be used for marketing purposes, but I'm afraid that there are implications I'm not considering.

Can anyone provide any insights about how I should approach this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Fantastic first question, by the way!

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding that it's one of those inconvenient questions that people who just want to do their jobs would like to bypass. I've been saying "a lot of really bad decisions were made in rooms just like this one with people just like you and me about problems just like this, so let's do our best to ensure we're not those people you read about."

Comment: Wanting to do things right is a good attitude. My personal opinion (as someone with no clue about PCI-compliance) to the question at hand is that that company has no need to get those addresses to conduct their business. If they need to call beforehand to conduct the shipping, you can tell the customers they need to get in touch.

Comment: I'm of the same opinion, personally. I would prefer to develop a solution that integrates our system with the final-mile company so we can handle the communications entirely, but that would be a big undertaking to develop and I don't know if I can sell it to the management at this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my concern is that providing this email address to other businesses in
>   our manufacturing and delivery pipeline will have PCI compliance
>   consequences.

No, PCI does not care about email address at all.  The only time it's mentioned in the DSS is to state you can't send unencrypted PAN via email.

> Can anyone provide any insights about how I should approach this problem?

If the company has a legitimate business need - if phone-related delays are credible - and your contract with them states they'll only use email for shipping purposes, then it's a reasonable thing to do.  If you don't trust them on either of those points, then you have a problematic relationship with your business partner.

You may also want to get an expert opinion (read: lawyer) about PII laws and what impact they have on the information sharing.  That will probably boil down to making sure the limited use of the PII is contractually stated, but YLMMV (Your Lawyer's Mileage May Vary).

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, but I will ask management to consult our lawyer about the potential for PII impact and, likely, to draft such an agreement. Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

PCI compliance is about payment data. An email address on it's own is not payment data, so it's nothing you have to worry about with regards to PCI compliance.

Generally speaking, the email address is not more or less important than the "customer's name, shipping address, and phone number". So if that was cleared to be sent to external parties, then email should be fine, too. I'm always assuming your customer *knows* and *consented* that you transfer that data over to the other company. Although for shipping, people would generally expect that. How would one ship goods without name or address.

To be safe, go to the person that cleared sending the current data over to the other company (maybe your company lawyer?) and let them clear the additional data as well. You need a real person that can take over real responsibility by signing off on something. "People on the internet said" is not going to be enough.

Comment: this answer reads like a rant against OP, please try to be more respectful.

Comment: @dandavis Maybe you are right, edited it.